# Bitcoin QT computer time

Tags: bitcoin-core, timestamp

Bitcoin qt says my computer time needs to be correct for it to work properly. My time is right to the minute, but not the second.

Will this cause a problem?

Comment: The Bitcoin client can fix the time if it's only an hour off by asking other clients what time it is. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7404/how-does-bitcoin-figure-out-what-time-it-is

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind will reject new blocks whose timestamp is more than a couple hours  ahead of the previous block.  This means you could be nearly two hours behind and your node would still accept most new blocks.